# don't stop service when activity is stop

Tags: android, android-service

I would like to know how to start a android service that continues to run even when the business is closed.

i use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTestService.class);          
bindService(intent,connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyTestService.class));
```

before

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTestService.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTestService.class);   
 startService(intent);
```

Comment: thank you but I would like keep my ServiceConnection to capture when the bind is performed

Comment: you can keep the two methods, simply called "startService" before.